# align element at the bottom of the row

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to get this UI element to align at the bottom of this row. I kinda went nuts with vertical-align everywhere but it didn't work. This HTML is generated with shiny, but if you don't know shiny and just tell me where to put that align I can probably figure out where to put it in shiny. Here's my shiny code that generated most of the code in the image, but I manually put in the "vertical-align"s manually after (without results). Should be easy to sub constants in for the variables if you want to test.

```
output$Y2AxisUI <- renderUI({
startMin <- round(as.numeric(DXMinMaxSubset()[1, 1])) - 1
startMax <- round(as.numeric(DXMinMaxSubset()[2, 1])) + 1
isolate({startPremium <- as.numeric(DXDataSubset()[1, 'premium'][[1]])})
finalMin <- min(startMin, startPremium + (startPremium - startMax), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            round(2)
finalMax <- max(startMax, startPremium + (startPremium - startMin), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            round(2)
fluidRow(
    column(1,
      numericInput("Y2MinNumInputBox",
                    label = NULL,
                    value = startMin)
    ),
  column(3,
    sliderInput("Y2AxisSlider",
                label = h4("Y2 axis range"),
                min = finalMin,
                max = finalMax,
                value = c(startMin,startMax),
                width = "100%")
  ),
  column(1,
   numericInput("Y2MaxNumInputBox",
         label = NULL,
         value = startMax)
  ),
  style = "padding-left: 40px")
})
```

[image: generated HTML]

edit to show the actual HTML code as requested

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 40px">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
      <input id="Y2MinNumInputBox" type="number" class="form-control shiny-bound-input" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group shiny-input-container" style="width: 100%;">
      <label class="control-label" for="Y2AxisSlider">
        <h4>Y2 axis range</h4>
      </label>
      <span class="irs js-irs-0 irs-with-grid"><span class="irs"><span class="irs-line" tabindex="-1"><span class="irs-line-left">
```

0
532.29
0
311
0 — 311


0


55



110


165



220



275


330



385



440



495
532.29

edit to show the resulting working shiny code, thanks in part to benjarwar's answer

```
fluidRow(
      column(12,
        div(id = "left",
            style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100px",
            numericInput("Y2MinNumInputBox",
                            label = NULL,
                            value = startMin)
        ),
        div(id = "center",
            style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; padding-right: 40px; padding-left: 40px; width: 400px;",
            sliderInput("Y2AxisSlider",
                        label = h4("Y2 axis range"),
                        min = finalMin,
                        max = finalMax,
                        value = c(startMin,startMax),
                        width = "100%")
        ),
        div(id = "right",
            style = "display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100px",
            numericInput("Y2MaxNumInputBox",
                         label = NULL,
                         value = startMax)
        )
      ),
      style = "padding-left: 40px")
```

Comment: Can you post the outputted HTML and CSS?

Comment: isn't that the HTML in the image? just ignore the vertical-aligns since I typed those in after it was generated

Comment: Yes, but you should always try to post the actual code in your description. If we have a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the specific issue you're having, it'll be easy to solve.

Comment: whoa weird I edited the post and it only shows a little bit of what I added...
to see it, go to edit, compare markdown side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to bottom align the contents of floated divs. The first problem here is that the divs are independent height-wise. So just because your middle div is taller, since both it and the left-most div are floated, setting vertical-alignment won't have any effect.

Try changing the styles of all three divs to `display: inline-block`. Once they're inline elements, then vertical-aligning to the bottom should work.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">Left div</div>
<div id="middle">Middle div</div>
<div id="right">Right div</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#middle {
  height: 200px;
  background: #fcc;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/35g59k5y/